# Building 3rd party server app to connect GCM from Android over xmpp

Tags: java, android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, server-application

I am building android app1 and app2, which will send data to each other based on this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html). The tutorial on GCM and xmpp is pretty straightforward. Google requires 3rd party server app with a backend to send upstream and downstream data to and from the android apps, which is something I couldn't understand. Should that app be an android app to? Or java app on a desktop(because it should run always nonstop)? I couldn't find a tutorial on building that server app. Can someone give me a hint or example?

Comment: It has to be a server (could be a desktop running on localhost or hosted on the cloud). There are Java and Python examples at the bottom of the XMPP GCM server [page](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#implement).